# Are there examples of the Court making a decision based on Jackson's Youngstown tripartite test, where they said the case was in the second category?

Tags: constitutional-law, us-supreme-court, us-president

In [Youngstown Sheet & Tube Co. v. Sawyer](https://supreme.justia.com/cases/federal/us/343/579/), in a popular concurring opinion, Justice Jackson setup a tripartite framework for evaluating the President's proper authority:

> When the President acts pursuant to an express or implied
> authorization of Congress, his authority is at its maximum, for it
> includes all that he possesses in his own right plus all that Congress
> can delegate. In these circumstances and in these only, may he be said
> . . . to personify the federal sovereignty. If his act is held
> unconstitutional under these circumstances it usually means that the
> Federal Government as an undivided whole lacks power.
>
> When the President acts in absence of either a congressional grant or
> denial of authority, he can only rely upon his own independent powers,
> but there is a zone of twilight in which he and Congress may have
> concurrent authority, or in which its distribution is uncertain.
> Therefore, congressional inertia, indifference or quiescence may
> sometimes at least as a practical matter, enable, if not invite,
> measure on independent responsibility. In this area, any actual test
> of power is likely to depend on the imperatives of events and
> contemporary imponderables rather than on abstract theories of law.
>
> When the President takes measures incompatible with the express or
> implied will of Congress, his power is at its lowest ebb, for then he
> can rely only upon his own constitutional powers minus any
> constitutional powers of Congress over the matter. Courts can sustain
> exclusive presidential control in such a case only by disabling the
> Congress from acting upon the subject. Presidential claim to a power
> at once so conclusive and preclusive must be scrutinized with caution
> for what is at stake is the equilibrium established by our
> constitutional system.

In [Zivotofsky v. Kerry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zivotofsky_v._Kerry) the court used this framework and did the analysis in the third category.

Are there any examples of cases where the court did the analysis in the second category?

Comment: Given that the guidance for the second category is essentially “gosh, that’s a tricky one”, it’s hard to see someone citing it as persuasive.

Comment: @Sneftel One of the main kinds of Presidential power in the second category are the President's foreign affairs powers, but I don't know if this case has been cited in support of them.